# Date formatting using data annotation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have this model with the following data annotation because I want to handle the date in this format : **dd.MM.yyyy**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DateRange(ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateBetween", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(WizardStrings))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime? BirthDate1 { get; set; }
```

In the view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate1 )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate1)
```

MVC still render this date with the following format : dd/MM/yyyy it seems like it doesn't take my data annotation into account.

See the rendered HTML :

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="La date de naissance est requise!" id="BirthDate1" name="BirthDate1" type="text" value="**9/9/1999 12:00:00 AM**">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before `DataFormatString` try adding `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include ApplyFormatInEditMode=true in the DisplayFormat attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string StartDate
        {
            get { return (startDateTime ?? new DateTime(1000, 01 ,01 )).ToString("G", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); }
        }
```

try other formats if that doesnt suit you